# VS Code autocomplete changed how it worked : flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code for flutter. 
Previously whenever I used it, when I choose the widget from suggestion drop down. This is how my auto-completed code would look,

```
FooWidget(bar: bar, baz:baz)
```

The required parameters automatically were typed.
Now, this is what happens

```
FooWidget(…)
```

This shows up for every autocomplete selection, irrespective if the widget has required parameters or not.

It was working till yesterday, I don't know why it changed.

---

Here's the Issue Link : https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4027

Comment: @nathanliang yes, even with every thing false and everything true, the autocomplete is broken

Comment: all extenstions are upto date.. (np you're trying to help that's a lot)

Comment: Gotcha, in that case then I think it's still something with settings. Have you checked `editor.suggest.<all the possible options for this>` like `editor.suggest.showWords`?

Comment: Every `editor.suggest` is enabled. I think this is a dart problem, than a vs code problem, i could be wrong though

Comment: Sorry for the late reply—have you tried `flutter doctor`?

Comment: @nathanliang Yes, All good with `flutter doctor`. I think It is a dart VS Code Extension problem. I have connected to the maintainers via discord and will file an issue on their github repo by today. I'll also add the link of that in the question as well. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: That's good to hear—I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help, but do let us know what you find out!